# inheritance of child from another child classes

Tags: c++, inheritance

I have the following classes ( Enemy class is the parent class and Boss and SuperDuperBoss are children classes). My problem with SuperDuperBoss

```
#ifndef _ENEMY_H
#define _ENEMY_H

#include <iostream>

    class Enemy
    {
    public:
        void SelectAnimation();
        inline void runAI() 
        {
            std::cout << "RunAI() is running ...\n";
        }

    private:
        int m_iHiPoints;
    };

    #endif
```

and this is the children classes

```
#ifndef BOSS_H
#define BOSS_H

#include "Enemy.h"



class Boss : public Enemy
{
 public:
    void runAI();
};

class SuperDuperBoss : public Boss
{
public:
    void runAI();
};

#endif
```

This is the main.cpp

```
#include "Enemy.h"
#include "Boss.h"

int main()
{
    Enemy enemy1;
    Boss boss1;
    SuperDuperBoss supBoss;

    enemy1.runAI();
    boss1.runAI();
    supBoss.runAI();  // <--- Error: linking

    return 0;
}
```

I have a linking error.

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "SuperDuperBoss::runAI()", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [test] Error 1
```

Comment: The declaration of `runAI()` in the child classes hides the implementation in the parent, and the linker error is because you haven't defined the actual function. Maybe you want to make those functions `virtual`?

Comment: You're using a [reserved identifier](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/228783/what-are-the-rules-about-using-an-underscore-in-a-c-identifier).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only declare `runAI` in the derived classes if you want to override the parent's definition. So, assuming you want to use the definition from `Enemy`, your derived classes should look like this:

```
class Boss : public Enemy
{
 public:
 //other bossy stuff
};

class SuperDuperBoss : public Boss
{
public:
//other superduperbossy stuff
};
```